# sum rows from two different data frames based on the value of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

`df1`

```
            ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0           11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    100
1           11  2023             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    200
2           11  2023           Berlin              Paris    300
3           12  2022          Newyork            Chicago    150
4           12  2022             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    250
5           12  2022           Berlin              Paris    400
```

`df2`

```
            ID  Year Primary_Location  Sales
0           11  2023          Chicago    150
1           11  2023            Paris    200
2           12  2022          Chicago    300
3           12  2022            Paris    350
```

I would like for each group having the same `ID` & `Year`:
to add the column `Sales` from `df2` to `Sales` in `df1` where `Primary_Location` in `df2` appear (contained) in `Secondary_Location` in `df1`.

For example: For `ID=11` & `Year=2023`, `Sales` for `Lyon` would be added to `Sales` for `Chicago` & `Sales` for `Paris` of `df_2`.

New `Sales` of `Paris` for that row would be 200+150+200=550.

The expected output would be :

```
df_primary_output



            ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0           11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    250
1           11  2023             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    550
2           11  2023           Berlin              Paris    500
3           12  2022          Newyork            Chicago    400
4           12  2022             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    900
5           12  2022           Berlin              Paris    750
```

**Here are the dataframes to start with :**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12],
                   'Year': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022],
                   'Primary_Location': ['NewYork', 'Lyon', 'Berlin', 'Newyork', 'Lyon', 'Berlin'],
                   'Secondary_Location': ['Chicago', 'Chicago,Paris', 'Paris', 'Chicago', 'Chicago,Paris', 'Paris'],
                   'Sales': [100, 200, 300, 150, 250, 400]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [11, 11, 12, 12],
                   'Year': [2023, 2023, 2022, 2022],
                   'Primary_Location': ['Chicago', 'Paris', 'Chicago', 'Paris'],
                   'Sales': [150, 200, 300, 350]
                   })
```

***EDIT: pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects***

Would be great if the solution could work for these inputs as well:

`df1`

```
       Day  ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0       1   11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    100
1       1   11  2023           Berlin            Chicago    300
2       1   11  2022          Newyork            Chicago    150
3       1   11  2022           Berlin            Chicago    400
```

`df2`

```
     Day    ID  Year Primary_Location  Sales
0     1     11  2023          Chicago    150
1     1     11  2022          Chicago    300
```

The expected output would be :

```
df_primary_output



       Day  ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0       1   11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    250
1       1   11  2023           Berlin            Chicago    450
2       1   11  2022          Newyork            Chicago    450
3       1   11  2022           Berlin            Chicago    700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
s = 'Secondary_Location'
(df1.assign(Secondary_Location = lambda x: x[s].str.split(','))
.explode(s)
.join(df2.set_index(['ID','Year','Primary_Location'])['Sales'].rename('Sales_2'),on = ['ID','Year',s])
.groupby(level=0)['Sales_2'].sum()
.add(df1['Sales']))
```

or

```
df3 = (df1.assign(Secondary_Location = df1['Secondary_Location'].str.split(',')) #split Secondary_Location column into list and explode it so each row has one value
.explode('Secondary_Location'))


(df3[['ID','Year','Secondary_Location']].apply(tuple,axis=1) #create a series where ID, Year and Secondary_Location are a combined into a tuple so we can map our series created below to bring in the values needed.
.map(df2.set_index(['ID','Year','Primary_Location'])['Sales']) #create a series with lookup values in index, and make a series by selecting Sales column
.groupby(level=0).sum() #when exploding the column above, the index was repeated, so groupby(level=0).sum() will combine back to original form.
.add(df1['Sales'])) #add in original sales column
```

Original Answer:

```
s = 'Secondary_Location'
(df.assign(Secondary_Location = lambda x: x[s].str.split(','))
.explode(s)
.join(df2.set_index(['ID','Year','Primary_Location'])['Sales'].rename('Sales_2'),on = ['ID','Year',s])
.groupby(level=0)
.agg({**dict.fromkeys(df,'first'),**{s:','.join,'Sales_2':'sum'}})
.assign(Sales = lambda x: x['Sales'] + x['Sales_2'])
.drop('Sales_2',axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0  11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    250
1  11  2023             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    550
2  11  2023           Berlin              Paris    500
3  12  2022          Newyork            Chicago    450
4  12  2022             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    900
5  12  2022           Berlin              Paris    750
```

Comment: Hi @rhug123 , thank you very much for your answer, I like it and it's working :) . could you please give me a bit more details on what's happening in this part of the code?: df3[['ID','Year','Secondary_Location']].apply(tuple,axis=1)
.map(df2.set_index(['ID','Year','Primary_Location'])['Sales'])
.groupby(level=0).sum()
.add(df1['Sales']))

Comment: I added some comments above

Comment: unfortunately the solution is not working for a slightly different data frame. Could you please help me :). I will add in the description the new dataframe. If I have a data frame without the rows containing ",". It seems that the new sales column is being doubled. Is there a way to make the solution more general to include this edge case? @rhug123

Comment: I just ran it with the new data and got the expected result using either of the first two solutions above. Would you mind double checking when you get a chance?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've changed my description again to reflect my actual dataframe/problem. I usually group with three columns, in the edit I added Day column. So the grouping would be on Day,Year,ID. in some edge cases ID & Day are the same for multiple rows. then the code breaks giving me a re-indexing error.   I guess because the indexes are not unique anymore. @rhug123

Comment: It's coming from this part : map(df2.set_index .. @rhug123

Comment: including your new day column in the set index part and when selecting the columns should work. just put `day` before id in the list of column names

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy your question...

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12],
                   'Year': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022],
                   'Primary_Location': ['NewYork', 'Lyon', 'Berlin', 'Newyork', 'Lyon', 'Berlin'],
                   'Secondary_Location': ['Chicago', 'Chicago,Paris', 'Paris', 'Chicago', 'Chicago,Paris', 'Paris'],
                   'Sales': [100, 200, 300, 150, 250, 400]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [11, 11, 12, 12],
                   'Year': [2023, 2023, 2022, 2022],
                   'Primary_Location': ['Chicago', 'Paris', 'Chicago', 'Paris'],
                   'Sales': [150, 200, 300, 350]
                   })

tot = []
def func(g, iterdf, len_df1, i = 0):
    global tot
    kv = {g['Primary_Location'].iloc[i]:g['Sales'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(g))}
    while i < len_df1:
        row = next(iterdf)[1]
        # Select specific df1 rows to modify by ID and Year criteria
        if g['ID'][g.index[0]]==row['ID'] and g['Year'][g.index[0]]==row['Year']:
            tot.append(row['Sales'] + sum([kv[town] for town in row['Secondary_Location'].split(',') if town in kv]))
        i+=1

df2.groupby(['ID', 'Year'], sort=False).apply(lambda g: func(g, df1.iterrows(), len(df1)))
df1['Sales'] = tot
print(df1)
```

**Result :**

```
   ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0  11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    250
1  11  2023             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    550
2  11  2023           Berlin              Paris    500
3  12  2022          Newyork            Chicago    450
4  12  2022             Lyon      Chicago,Paris    900
5  12  2022           Berlin              Paris    750
```

Are you sure of the result in line 3, my script found 450 and not 400 ?

**Explanation :**

**1 -** `group(...).apply(...)` sends two groups from `df2` one by one to `func()` :

```
   ID  Year Primary_Location  Sales
0  11  2023          Chicago    150
1  11  2023            Paris    200
```

```
   ID  Year Primary_Location  Sales
2  12  2022          Chicago    300
3  12  2022            Paris    350
```

**2 -** `kv` returns dictionnaries from `df2` like this :

(each iteration corresponds to a group ie ID + Year)

```
call 1 - {'Chicago': 100, 'Paris': 200}
call 2 - {'Chicago': 300, 'Paris': 350}
```

**3 -** Function `while` followed by used of `next(iterator)` allows to explore rows in `g` (group) one by one :

```
while i < len_df1:
    row = next(iterdf)[1]
...
    i+=1
```

**4 -** The `if` condition in `while` loop allows to filter `df1` rows in order that `ID` and `Year` corresponds to `df2`'s ones.

And for each correspondance to append to the global list `tot` `df1` and `df2` sales values

**5 -** `tot` is a global list for memorizing values and is passed to `df1` for the `Sales` column creation :

```
df1['Sales'] = tot
```

**Result with the new dataframes sample :**

```
   ID  Year Primary_Location Secondary_Location  Sales
0  11  2023          NewYork            Chicago    250
1  11  2023           Berlin            Chicago    450
2  11  2022          Newyork            Chicago    450
3  11  2022           Berlin            Chicago    700
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me your solution, I'm having a bit of hard time understanding it. what's iterdf ? @Laurent B.

Comment: iterdf is the pandas iterator df1.iterrows() which allows you to read the dataframe row by rows, like slicing the matrix in rows : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html (I am out, I will give you more details later)

Comment: I sligthy modify the script, it will work with new dataframe